# Signing installer for windows app using electron builder

Tags: desktop-application, electron, signtool, electron-builder

I am using [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) for creating installer for my desktop app in windows by command

```
build -w
```

it cerates folder win-unpacked(for build) and win(for installer)

here is my package.json

```
 {
"name": "CoDesktopElectron",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "CoDesktopElectron",
"homepage": "https://app.onepgr.com/",
"author": "ankur",
"private": true,
scripts": {
"postinstall": "install-app-deps",
"start": "npm install && npm run compile && electron ./app",
"compile": "rimraf app/out && tsc",
"pack": "npm run compile && build --dir",
"dist": "npm run compile && build",
"release": "npm run compile && build"
},
"build": {
"appId": "org.develar.onshape",
"category": "public.app-category.graphics-design",
"dmg": {
  "contents": [
    {
      "x": 110,
      "y": 150
    },
    {
      "x": 240,
      "y": 150,
      "type": "link",
      "path": "/Applications"
    }
  ]
},
"win": {
  "publish": null
},
"linux": {
  "publish": null,
  "target": [
    "deb",
    "AppImage"
  ]
 }
 },
"devDependencies": {
"asar": "^0.7.2",
"electron": "1.4.3",
"electron-builder": "^7.14.2",
"electron-installer-windows": "^0.2.0",
"electron-prebuilt": "^0.31.0",
"fs-jetpack": "^0.7.0",
"gulp": "^3.9.0",
"gulp-copy": "0.0.2",
"gulp-uglify": "^1.3.0",
"gulp-usemin": "^0.3.12",
"q": "^1.4.1",
"rcedit": "^0.3.0",
"rimraf": "^2.5.4",
"typescript": "^2.0.3"
 }
}
```

i want to sign my windows installer(i have certificate in .p12 format)
i know we have to do it by CSC_LINK and CSC_KEY_PASSWORD but not getting any example of how to do it.

please help me out of this!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not try this yet (thus no answer), but I found [this](https://discuss.atom.io/t/signing-windows-app-installer/32511/6) discussion  which contained this example `"dist:win": "export CSC_LINK=file:///tmp/my-win-developer-cert-win.p12; read -s -p \"Certificate Password: \" certPassword; export CSC_KEY_PASSWORD=\"$certPassword\"; npm run clean:win && build --win"`