# How to sign in windows installer using electron builder

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am configuring package.json for windows. The packager is working fine. But, I also want to sign my windows installer file and unable to do.

I have gone through this tutorial [WindowsConfiguration](https://www.electron.build/configuration/win#WindowsConfiguration-sign) and got this line:

> sign String | (configuration: CustomWindowsSignTaskConfiguration) =>
>   Promise - The custom function (or path to file or module id) to sign
>   Windows executable.

The problem is, I am not getting how to create JS file for windows installer signing and what parameters I have to use for its configurations. Thanks for your time.

Comment: https://discuss.atom.io/t/signing-windows-app-installer/32511/6

Comment: Thank you for reference @KenWhite. I am looking for something which windows-installer (https://github.com/electron/windows-installer) did. A custom sign certificate. But due to some performance issue, I dropped that package and started using electron-builder. Now I want same kind of functionality in electron-builder as it already has but no tutorial available for it.

Comment: That link came from the comment to [Signing installer for windows app using electron builder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40765246/62576). Are you sure you read it completely?

Comment: That was a nice link. I am not trying to add any windows certificate but instead, I am trying to add a custom sign. I don't know whether it is possible or not. In case of win-installer, it was doing that. In short, I just want to add publisher in my installer file

Comment: Yes, that's done with a code signing certificate, but regardless of which certificate you use the process is the same.

Comment: So, do I have to get code signing certificate from windows?

Comment: No. You have to get a code signing certificate from someone, or generate your own (which will not be trusted). Google *code signing certificate*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With electron-builder, the only thing you need to sign your Windows application is to set this two Environment Variables `CSC_LINK` and `CSC_KEY_PASSWORD` as explained here : https://www.electron.build/code-signing.

-- alternative --

You can do the same by setting this in your `package.json` like this (but not recommended):

```
"build": {
  ...
  "win": {
    ...
    "certificateFile": "path to your cert",
    "certificatePassword": "the password of your cert"
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to generate any non-trusted certificate by my own?

Comment: Yes, you can use a self-signing certificate [(see this issue)](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/458). But to release your production app, it is better to buy a code-signing certificate (to not have untrusted alert on Windows) and an Apple certificate for macOS if you want that your user can simply install your app.

Comment: The issue reference you provided is for Mac. Is there any ref for windows? Before this, I know electron-builder has a feature to create and sign the untrusted certificate. But there is no documentation provided for it. Do you know how can this achieved?

Comment: Can't believe this is the only thing out there that truly shows how to sign the damn exe.

Comment: This solution will not work with EV code signing

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own signtool to sign what you need.

Firstly, you need signtool.exe from Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/signtool-exe

Then call `child_process.exec` to sign your file, for example:

```
exec(`call "${PATH_TO_SIGNTOOL_EXE}" sign /f "${KEY_SHA256}" /p ${PASS_KEY_SHA256} /fd sha256 /tr "http://sha256timestamp.ws.symantec.com/sha256/timestamp" /td sha256 /as /v "${FILE_TO_SIGN}"`)
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for providing this details, I am looking forward to using it. But, first of all, I am searching for any electron-builder configuration because I have an auto-update server and I am using electron-builder configuration to publish my application.

Comment: So you just need to set env vars CSC_LINK and CSC_KEY_PASSWORD