# Codesigning electron app for windows (on windows)

Tags: electron, code-signing, electron-builder

As it says in the title, this is what im trying to do: using windows 10, codesign my electron app using the certificate purchased from a third party vendor (which is in p12 format).

I've read the docs here: https://www.electron.build/configuration/win and here: https://www.electron.build/code-signing
And realise that I need to provide a path to the certificate file and password (if one is set) using the appropriate keys (certificateFile  and certificatePassword).

I've also seen these answers:

- [How to sign in windows installer using electron builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50874926/how-to-sign-in-windows-installer-using-electron-builder)

(There's also loads of questions and answers referring to people building for windows on mac, but that's not what im doing here)

But this doesnt seem to address the question.

These are how the lines in my package.json are set referring to the relevant path/password:

```
"certificateFile ": "./certificate_file.p12",
"certificatePassword ": "password"
```

I realise that it is better to have these set in a .env file and read them from there, which I intend to do later. But as I understand it, this should suffice shouldnt it?

My build command is:

```
"build": "electron-builder build"
```

And this produces the following:

[image]

But there is no mention of signing taking place at all. If Im being royally stupid, please feel free to point out where ^_^ many thanks in advance!

***Updates***

- Queried with project maintainers on github, code signing is supposed to take place automatically provided the variables are set correctly, see convo here: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/6895)

Answer (score 1):

It may be **significantly** simpler to sign your exe OUTSIDE of electron builder. In which case, the approach I took was to use [SSL.com's SSL manager GUI](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/using-your-code-signing-certificate/).

You can read about it toward the bottom of [this page](https://www.ssl.com/how-to/using-your-code-signing-certificate/) and see their documentation of the tool [here](https://www.ssl.com/guide/ssl-manager-documentation).

About a week looking into codesigning with electron builder, still not entirely sure how to do it.
About 5 mins using this tool. Done.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the whole process but I had to fumble around for a few days to get it working.

In my package.json file I have a build object like this:

```
"build":
    ...
    "win": {
      "certificateFile": "private/mycertificate.pfx",
      "verifyUpdateCodeSignature": true,
      "publisherName": [
        "My Company Name"
      ]
    },
```

Then before publishing I run this in windows powershell to set the env variable:

```
setx CSC_KEY_PASSWORD my-certifcate-password-here
```

Then finally:

```
electron-builder -w
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a code signing certificate, then you can add the following configuration in your `package.json` file.

```
"build": {
...
"win": {
...
"certificateFile": "path to your certificate file (certificate.pfx)",
"certificatePassword": "the password of your cert"
   }
}
```

Kindly remember, the password is the same password that you've used to export `.pfx` file from `.cer` file using openssl